# I'm trying to upload files to the dropbox with laravel

Tags: laravel, dropbox

I'm trying to upload files to the dropbox with laravel. I followed the steps I read in the documentation, but I'm not getting it.

I installed the Dropbox adapter and right after that, I created the provider as the name that is in the documentation and put the code that is also in the documentation

**Provider:**

```
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use League\Flysystem\Filesystem;
use Spatie\Dropbox\Client as DropboxClient;
use Spatie\FlysystemDropbox\DropboxAdapter;

class DropboxServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
/**
 * Register any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    //
}

/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    Storage::extend('dropbox', function ($app, $config) {
        $client = new DropboxClient(
            $config['authorization_token']
        );

        return new Filesystem(new DropboxAdapter($client));
    });
}
}
```

there in the filesystem I created a disk

```
'dropbox' => [
        'driver' => 'dropbox',
        'authorization_token' => env('DROPBOX_TOKEN'),
    ],
```

In app I added the following line

```
// Dropbox
    App\Providers\DropboxServiceProvider::class,
```

In env. I added the following lines. The access token and app secret are from the api created in the dropbox

```
DROPBOX_TOKEN = <REDACTED>
DROPBOX_SECRET = <REDACTED>
```

View:

```
<div>
    <form action="{{ route('uploadStore') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        @csrf
        <input type="file" name="image">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
    </form>
</div>

<div>
    @if($errors->any())
        <h4>{{$errors->first()}}</h4>
    @endif
</div>
```

And the controller:

```
protected function index() {
    $files = Storage::allFiles('teste-gobsruiz01');
    return view('index', [
        'files' => $files,
    ]);
}
protected function store(Request $request) {
    $file = $request->file("image");
    $is_file_uploaded = Storage::disk('dropbox')->put('teste-gobsruiz01',$file);

    if($is_file_uploaded){
        return Redirect::back()->withErrors(['msg'=>'Succesfuly file uploaded to dropbox']);
      } else {
        return Redirect::back()->withErrors(['msg'=>'file failed to uploaded on dropbox']);
      } 
}
```

I created the api in the dropbox. The name is teste-gobsruiz01. I also created the two routes, get and post.

If someone please can help me, I appreciate it. I've been trying for a long time

Comment: You should not share your access token or app secret. I redacted it from your post, but you should [revoke](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#auth-token-revoke) that access token since you posted it publicly.

Comment: As for the question, what specifically isn't working?

Comment: When I place the image in the input and click to send. It is not sent.

Comment: Does laravel.log say anything?

Comment: I did not understand. The validation are you talking about?